# laravel Form Validation errors

Tags: laravel, validation

version: laravel 5.7

Router:

```
Route::get('regist','User\RegistController@registView');
Route::post('regist','User\RegistController@regist');
```

Form:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="/regist">
.....
</form>
```

Validate:

```
$this->validator=Validator::make($input,$rule,$message);  
if($this->validator->fails()){
return \Redirect::back()->withErrors($this->err());
}
```

The Problem:

Do not display an error message.Need to press Enter in the address bar to reload the page.Want to use the Validateor::make method.How can I modify it?

Comment: Change `$this->err()` to `$this->validator->err()`

Answer (score 0):

If the validation worked, did your put the error message to be displayed on the page you redirected to?

for example in your blade page did you do something like below?

```
@if(count($errors->all()) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <p><b>Required Fields Missing!</b></p>
        <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

I will show you a simple example, if you are in the controller use the validator facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

In the conroller user the below code

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) //use of request
{
    $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
    ], [
        'name.required' => 'Name is required',
    ]);

}
```

If validation fails it will automatically redirect back or you could use a validator fail statement and send a modified message.

After that you should put an if statement to display the error message as below:

```
@if(count($errors->all()) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <p><b>Required Fields Missing!</b></p>
        <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Or if you have only one defined error message use:

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
       { Session::get('success') }}
   </div>
@endif
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For add validation on form you can use Laravel Request Validation classes. which will help you to pull validation in separate class.

Here is the reference for request classes :- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation

That will help you to pull validation and also improvements in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if ($errors->any())
   <div class="alert alert-danger">
     <ul>
       @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
           <li>{{ $error }}</li>
       @endforeach
      </ul>
   </div>
@endif
```